# Why does the mesh look so strange?

Tags: rendering, mesh, normals

It seems to be related to the mesh texture~

[image: Mesh]

[link to mesh](https://rec.ustc.edu.cn/share/f3061920-f272-11ea-b46a-8b5a6b9202e3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mesh has custom normals.

Uncheck "autosmooth" in the property panel (object data tab, normals section).

[image]

Comment: Emm, pretty nice~

Does it have the function of recalculating vertex normal?

Comment: Unchecking autosmooth involves this calculation.